Flutter internal error while using signInWithEmailAndPassword
I'm trying to create a sign-in form using flutter and firebase. I'm facing the following error while using the signInWithEmailAndPassword function:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/internal-error] An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
Code:
body: Column(children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _email,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Email"),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _password,
            obscureText: true,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: "Password"),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final email = _email.text;
              final password = _password.text;
              await Firebase.initializeApp(
                options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
              );
              final userCredential = 
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email, password: password
                );
              print(userCredential);
            },
            child: const Text("Register"),
          )
        ])

I tried unrestricting my API keys from the Google Cloud Console, but that didn't work. I'm using an IOS simulator. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

initialize the firebase in the main function with calling  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

@MunsifAli should I put it in the runApp()? Where exactly should I put it?

not in the runApp direclty in the main function check the below answer.

Try to catch the error you get and print it! Then you probably get some more information. Maybe your input is incorrect.
Try this:
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch  (e) {
  print('Failed with error code: ${e.code}');
  print(e.message);
}

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors

Thanks, I found out it was a configuration not found error.

do firebase intialization in the main function like this:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}


Thanks for the answer, however it did not work.

it worked? or still getting error?

No, I'm still getting the error.

same error or different? wrap it in try-catch block and see what is the error.

It's a Configuration Not Found error. Thanks!
